# Transaction support between queues on RabbitMQ via .NET Client

Tags: c#, rabbitmq

The methods below are provided on RabbitMQ .NET Client 5.0.1:

```
IModel
        void TxCommit();        
        void TxRollback();        
        void TxSelect();
```

My questions is that, is the scenario below supported with transnational atomicity.

1 Read messages off queue A,

2 then send messages to queues B and C,

3 commit transaction.

Please code example if it is supported.

If it is not supported, what are alternative solutions?

Comment: Did the [documentation](https://www.rabbitmq.com/semantics.html) not answer your question?

Comment: Specifically "AMQP guarantees atomicity only when transactions involve a single queue,"

Comment: I know the link, but am not 100% sure. Specifically, what is the difference between columns "AMQP 0-9-1" and  "RabbitMQ >= 2.8.0" on the link? For example RabbitMQ .NET Client 5 should have support of AMQP 0-9-1?

Comment: No, this is not supported, and no, there is no way to support it. What you are asking simply makes no sense as a transaction.